# Exception: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00

Tags: java, swing, io

When I query through the EJB interface for a entity, under the console it is ok, but switch to query from Swing it throw this exception.

The exception:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: failed to unmarshal MY_ENTITY****; nested exception is: 
    java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
    at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:219)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.invoke(BasicRemoteRef.java:224)
    at ***.****_6ndxy4_EOImpl_922_WLStub.getProductInformation(Unknown Source)
    at MY_CLASS****.getProductInformation(*****.java:460)
    at ******$5.run(OrigBlotter.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1356)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1642)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1323)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:195)
    at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.readObject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:565)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:191)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.ObjectIO.readObject(ObjectIO.java:62)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:217)
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code. And yes don;t forget to include the relevant stack trace.

Answer (score 7):

It turns out it is a JRE bug.
As my console env is 1.5 and swing is 1.6:

Bug reference:

- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6554519
- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6434149

We need to pass this argument to the JVM

> -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true

Comment: I can't see anything in that bug about "java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00".

Comment: Which is the JVM version you say ?@aaron

Answer (score 1):

This exception is generated when the the class corresponding to the serialized object that is found by the JVM has the same serialVersionUid as the serialised class, but is actually a different version (ie: changes were made to the class without changing the version id).

Check that you have the relevant jar's/class files in the class path?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not correct. You either get a class not found if the class is not on the classpath or an InvalidClassException if it's a different version. Can you show an example?

Comment: Gosh, that was a good long while ago.. Try it and see what happens. I recall that attempting to deserialise an object for which a class was not found (or perhaps a class with the same name, but not the same?? eg: different version) caused a StreamCorruptedException. Cant recall if the "type code 00" part was there too, but I think so. I put this answer here as it was tricky for me to track down and google showed me this question along the way :)

Comment: For the record, it was mismatched jar file versions that caused the error for me. The different class versions had the same serialisation uid, so a StreamCorruptedException instead of the exception for mismatched versions.

Comment: I had the same exception when i upgraded the a log4j jar in build.gradle.This error is gone when i removed the new version and pointed to old version that was already in gradle cache. Any idea how to upgrade the jar in proper way any idea ?

Comment: This error was simply a mistake of eclipse that it kept showing stale. Deleting the eclipse errors manually and then I did following , that solved the problem and generated the war file.
1. Open command prompt in the same location of gradle project and execute gradle --refresh-dependencies
2. Run Gradle clean in eclipse, that will make sure all errors are gone rebuilding now in eclipse will generate WAR or JAR as clean without errors