# java multithreading two thread try to readobject() from same object input stream at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading

I try to make a card game.I have a thread problem. I construct objectinputstream only once and then just send a reference to it to the other Thread and two thread try to read an object from same objectinputstream at the same time.The same problem is [java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775709/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-type-code-00) but it didn't solved.

ClientService Thread:

```
    while (true) {
        try {
            Message message = (Message) in.readObject();
            handleClientMessage(message);
            if (message.getType() == Message.messageType.ClientDisconnect) {
                break;
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientServiceThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientServiceThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Game Thread

```
public void run() {
    startGame();

    while (true) {
        try {
            Message msg = (Message) inPlayer1.readObject();
            handlePlayerMessage(msg);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

in and inplayer1 the same objectinputstream.I get an exception : java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00 .Two classes make a different job only this part is similar.Please give an advise how I solve this problem.Is there any way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just have one thread reading the stream and doing everything which needs to be done for each object.

This thread can do all the work of the two threads and/or you can have it message between threads to have other threads do additional work.

Answer (score 1):

If `ObjectInputStream` is constructed only once and then just passed a reference of it to the other Thread then simply enclose the access of this object inside `synchronized` block to make sure that only one thread can access this object at a time.

---

**Assumption:** both `in` and `inPlayer1` are representing to same object that is actually a `ObjectInputStream` and shared between different threads.

ClientService Thread:

```
... 
Message message = null;
synchronized (in) {
    message = (Message) in.readObject();
}
...
```

Game Thread:

```
... 
Message msg = null;
synchronized (inPlayer1) {
    msg = (Message) inPlayer1.readObject();
}
...
```

Comment: thanks but with this way only one thread read the message(Sometimes gamescreen sometimes clientservice) I want to both threads reach the same message at the same time .

Comment: you haven't mentioned this thing. No worries at least it will solve the `StreamCorruptedException`.