# Java Voice Chat Error

Tags: java, objectinputstream, voice-recording, javax.sound.sampled

I am making a voice chat program.  I have two servers one for voice and one for messages.  When I connect two people I get this error, Thank you in advance. I attached the client code, ClientAudio code and the Client receive code

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readBlockHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2508)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.refill(ObjectInputStream.java:2543)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2702)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:865)
at client.chat$ClientAudioRec.run(chat.java:388)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

its calling the error on

```
try {
    bytesRead = ((ObjectInput) i2).read(inSound, 0, inSound.length);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

***Code***

```
    public class Client implements Runnable {                                                   // CLIENT
    private String msg;
    public void run() {
        try {
            s1 = new Socket(ipAddress, port);
            s2 = new Socket(ipAddress, 1210);
            o1 = new ObjectOutputStream(s1.getOutputStream());
            o1.writeObject(name);
            serverListModel.addElement(name);
            i1 = new ObjectInputStream(s1.getInputStream());
            Thread voice = new Thread(new ClientAudio());
            voice.start();
            while(true) {
                msg = (String) i1.readObject();
                    String[] namePart = msg.split("-");
                    if(namePart[0].equals("AddName") && !namePart[1].equals(name) && !serverListModel.contains(namePart[1])) {
                        serverListModel.addElement(namePart[1]);
                    }
                    if(namePart[0].equals("RemoveName") && !namePart[1].equals(name)) {
                        serverListModel.removeElement(namePart[1]);
                    }
                    if(!msg.equals(null) && !namePart[0].equals("AddName") && !namePart[0].equals("RemoveName")) {
                        chatWindow.append(msg+"\n");
                    }
                }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            chatWindow.append("Server Closed");
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                s1.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            mainWindow(true);
        }
    }
}

public class ClientAudio implements Runnable {                                                  // CLIENT AUDIO
    public void run() {
        try {
            o2 = new ObjectOutputStream(s2.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("AUDIO");
            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] soundData = new byte[1];
            Thread car = new Thread(new ClientAudioRec());
            car.start();

            while(true) {
                bytesRead = mic.read(soundData, 0, bytesRead);
                if(bytesRead >= 0) {
                    o2.write(soundData, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class ClientAudioRec implements Runnable {                                                       // CLIENT AUDIO REC

    public void run() {
        i2 = new ObjectInputStream(s2.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("REC");
        SourceDataLine inSpeaker = null;
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, af);
        try {
            inSpeaker = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            inSpeaker.open(af);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e1) {
            System.out.println("ERROR 22");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] inSound = new byte[100];
        inSpeaker.start();
        while(bytesRead != -1)
        {
            try{
                bytesRead = ((ObjectInput) i2).read(inSound, 0, inSound.length);
                } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(bytesRead >= 0)
            {
                inSpeaker.write(inSound, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a byte array with only 1 byte in it

Comment: thats not the problem

Comment: The problem has to do with i2, yet you haven't shown us that code

Comment: I added the client code and the client audio class and the client receive class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775709/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-type-code-00)

Comment: You are trying to use i2 from 2 different threads, which is causing your problem. Synchronize it.

Comment: I moved the initialization of i2 to the same thread.  I am not using i2 anywhere else.

Comment: This is my version before i implemented it into my current program and it works fine. [previous code](http://pastebin.com/a5eDYisA)