# Why client input.readObject sometimes return "null" and sometimes works fine?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to make a Client/Server program that uses tcp java connection and im testing it on the same machine (both Server and client) using localhost IP and port 12345.

I use ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream to receive and send messages.
**Sometimes** my program works **perfect**, it send the right messages as i want, but **sometimes** (*in random time/stage of the program*) one of my client "loses" the connection and he gets into an infinite loop printing **"null"** or **"invalid type code:54"** without doing any code changes.

Im getting no errors just the server prints **"Connection reset"** in loop and the client the **"null"** or **"invalid type code:54"** from the **catch (IOException e)**.

I will show you just the **basic of my Code**.

server:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //--------BASIC CODE used for connection stuff below----//
         server = new ServerSocket(12345);
         connection =server.accept();
         Thread thread =new Thread(new ClientThread(connection,GRM...));
         thread.start();
         output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
         output.flush();
         input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    }
    --------------//---------thread for each client----------//--------------
    do{
           try{
             message=(String) input.readObject();
             if(message.startsWith("SOMENTHING"))//...some tcode
             if(message.equals("SEND")){
                 String message="hi";
                 output.writeObject("Chat:"+message);output.flush();
                 UserW.writeObject(message);UserW.flush();
                 //UserW is an output from another client stored in the server
             }
             catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
                System.out.print("\nUnknown object");
             }catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
             }    
     }while(!message.equals("DISCONNECT"));
```

Client:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        connection=new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"),12345);
        //...... same logic with streams......//
        }
        //-------thread that receives from server-----//
        do{
          try{
           String message=(String) input.readObject();
           //.....some code....//
          }catch( ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
            System.out.print("\nUnknown object");
          }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }
        }while(true);
```

Comment: You seem to be opening two ObjectOutputStream on the same server socket, which is probably causing this error.

Comment: I open an ObjectOutputStream for each new connection and i process them in a new thread...if you mean that

Comment: No I mean your server has `output.writeObject;               UserW.writeObject;` Which seems to point that one thread (your server) handle two ObjectOutputStream which is not a good idea at all

Comment: Ok i see what you mean, but i have seen a tutorial for a chat app and it did the same thing to broadcast the message to the others.The UserW is a reference from another clients socket output STORED in the server....in the other hand my problem appears most when i have to send messages to others so you may have a point there. But how im supposed to send messages to others?

Comment: No need to believe me, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10777950/4121573 or here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2395269/4121573   Worst case, you might try an `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` between both calls

Comment: One more thing.....might the problem be solved if i use WriteChars instead of WriteObject? *(I'm not trying it yet  because i have 1000 lines in my program and i want to be sure first)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So i made some tests with another simpler Server/Client program i created and
i figured that when the server sends **two or more messages simuntaniously** the *input.read()* of the client gets "confused" and wont read the messages properly making the server do "connection reset" and the client give the "invalid code" errors

My solution for that problem (*that works*) is to create a synchronized method of sending messages to the clients, on Server site, but i dont like it because the Server performance will decrease(*i think*).As a second solution i was thinking on the client site to make something like a buffer but i don't know if that is possible.

If somebody has a better solution i would loved to hear it.

**UPDATE**:Best solution is using using **BufferedReader** for input and a **PrintWriter** for output,instead of streams.

P.S. A big thank to asettouf, he lead me to the right way.

Comment: You only have multiple threads using same streams because of a variable scoping mistake. This solution sequentializes all I/O to all clients. Not at all desirable.

Answer (score 0):

> Why client `readObject()` sometimes return null

It isn't. `readObject()` is not returning null. You are *printing* null in the `catch` block, because you caught an `IOException` with no message, possibly `EOFException` for example, which should cause you to close the socket and break out of the read loop.

The actual issue is a concurrency problem, here:

```
Thread thread =new Thread(new ClientThread(connection,GRM...));
thread.start();
output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
output.flush();
input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
```

The `output` and `input` variables should be members of `ClientThread`, not this class, and they should be initialized in `ClientThread.run()`, not in its constructor, and certainly not here.

Comment: I solved my problem, i have already write the answer.I can't understand what u mean probably my knowledge  on java isn't so good